# Postgres 9.1.24 > FATAL: SSL is not supported by this build

Tags: postgresql, postgis

We're backing up an old server with:
Postgres 9.1.24
Postgis 2.1

But before we can say "it's done", they (obviously) want me to build a local installation and ensure the restore works fine (heh...)

What I currently have:
- Postgres 9.5 installed with apt-get (for other stuff unrelated to this)
- Postgres 9.1.24; downloaded the tar.gz and manually installed and configured
* PostGIS 2.1, GEOS 3.4.2, GDAL all installed for the 9.1.24 version

Postgres 9.1.24 was working fine (before I started with PostGIS) but I had to restart for other stuff and now it won't even start; the error is quite weird:
*FATAL:  SSL is not supported by this build*

I've gone through the pg_conftool checking and changing all the necessary information (SSL is off? disable? couldn't find it, tried with both)

I'm quite at a loss now, nothing I try works :S

Does anyone have any idea/suggestion? Thanks·

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql 9.5 and Postgis 2.1 are [said](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostgreSQLPostGIS) to be incompatible.